# rails redirect to edit page when submitting the form with the params of saved form

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I'm new to rails,I've created a customer_details form.when I submit a form by clicking save button It should be saved and redirected to the edit page with all the contents of the form.so that i can download the form using download button.[This is what im getting after saved the form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zaLvh.png)

```html
def create
    @customer_detail = CustomerDetail.new(customer_detail_params)
    @customer_detail.company_profile_id = current_user.company_profile.id
    respond_to do |format|
      if @customer_detail.save
        format.html { redirect_to edit_customer_detail_path(@customer_detail), notice: 'customerDetails was successfully created.' }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
      end
    end
  end
def edit
   @customer_details = CustomerDetail.find(params[:id])
  end
```

problem is,when I click save button it redirects to the edit path.but without any contents of form. what should I do now to get the form in edit_path?.can someone plz help me.thanks in advance!!

Comment: add edit form and edit action

Comment: i have edited my question with edit action.

Comment: Add your edit.html.erb in question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this `format.html { render 'edit', notice: 'customerDetails was successfully created.' }`

Tried on my app and it works as expected.

Comment: I've tried it.It redirects to the edit page but not with the contents of the form.I want the form to be displayed.so that i use download it using download button.can u plz help more

Comment: I've not included anything to edit.html.haml.I left it empty.shall i render my form.html.haml to the edit page ?

Comment: @HariPrakash yea, it should be same to form.html.haml